# Debugging a connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications, connection-string

I've a website that works fine in local mode with local SqlExpress. When I publish and put the final server connection string, I keep getting the helpless `500 - Internal server error`.

I tried to use the final server connection string in local debug mode, but even then it uses local SqlExpress instance, I don't know why! So again it is of no use. Here's the connection string:

```
<add name="MainDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=rose.arvixe.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I use these infos to connect to the server with Management Studio and it works fine.

Is it possible to at least get a clear error message?

After 7 hours on this problem, I beg for help.

EDIT: If I remove all data acces from the page, it works. As soon as I'm creating a context, the error occurs.

Comment: Are you completely sure it's the connection string that's causing the issue?  You might try looking at the Event logs on the IIS server and see if it's throwing exceptions that can't be written out over the wire and so is just returning a generic 500 internal server error.

Comment: If you're using Internet Explorer you can often get more information by going to Tools | Options | Advanced and turning off "friendly http error messages" - based on your error configuration, you will see something that might give you a clue. Could be something as simple as the version of ASP.NET installed on the server is not what you target, the App Pool runtime is incorrect etc

Comment: Perhaps you can download a HTTP listener like Fiddler and take note of what response the remote server returns you. If you actually get the server error notification on the browser, then perhaps you can use browser debugging tools such as Developer Tools for Chrome...

Comment: @Adrian : I added some clarification. In fact, I can't be 100% sur that it is the connection sting because the error message is of no use. Firebug added nothing and IE tool simply says that the server response is the error

Comment: @Mathieu Is the final server at the same network as the database server? Are you sure that the final server can reach database server? Are you able to connect remotely to the final server terminal (RDP)?

Comment: to get a clear error msg modify web.config.set <system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">.and if there are any code executed when loading the page(which gives u the error msg).add Try Catch block.then u'll get a clear error msg

Comment: You might find the error in the Windows Event Log too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're wanting is to see some helpful debug info instead of just "server 500", you need to a) turn off custom errors (so IIS will serve up a technical description of the error) and b) turn on tracing.

1. In the web.config, in the  node, add the following:

> ```
> <trace
>  enabled="true"
>  requestLimit="100"
>  pageOutput="false"
>  traceMode="SortByTime"
>  localOnly="false"
>     />
>
> <customErrors mode="Off" />
> ```

1. Save the file
2. Navigate to the page that's giving you the server 500 error. Hopefully you'll see some more detailed info now.
3. Navigate to [your web URL]/trace.axd and click one of the traces.  This should give you even more information about what's going on in your page.

Comment: Strangely, it works if I remove the context, but as soon as I get an error 500, I get the same error 500 when navigating to /trace.axd